# View Exception remarks with Intellisense *pop-up*

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I am going through a legacy code-base and documenting out various exception conditions, e.g.

```
''' <summary>
''' Retrieves the configuration values.
''' </summary>
''' <returns>An IDictionary representing the configuration values section of this application.</returns>
''' <exception cref="ConfigurationException">A configuration file could not be loaded.</exception>
```

This works as expected for `Summary`, but I am not seeing my Exception remarks when I try to use the intellisense pop-up

[image: no exception detail shown alongside method summary]

I would expect to see "A configuration file could not be loaded." here, but I am not.

Is this expected behavior?

Is there a setting somewhere that will let me see more information without leaving my current editor window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your XML comment definition into my VB file and got the same result as yours, please have a look at this:  [Recommended XML Tags for Documentation Comments (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-xml-tags-for-documentation-comments) and it seems you need to adjust your XML comment definition like the following screenshot:
[image]

As far as I know, some tags like 'para', 'returns' need to put inside the tag 'summary' to make it works, you need to rearrange those tags to make it display as your expected.

*>> Is there a setting somewhere that will let me see more information without leaving my current editor window?*

You can right click the **ConfigSettings** and choose ‘**Peek Definition’**, it will display a small window to display the detail information about it.

Comment: That's kinda cheating.. you're writing a multi-line <summary>, instead of having VS show the detailed description for the <exception> xmldoc